# How to make flutter card auto adjust its height depend on content

Tags: flutter, gridview, flutter-layout, height

In the project, I'm using images and text inside the flutter card, but the card returns a fixed height. and then I also tried just using a card with an empty value, but it still returns a fixed height. what should I do to make the height of the card auto adjust with content?

```
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final title = 'Food Recipes';
    return MaterialApp(
      title: title,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(title),
        ),
        body: GridView.builder(
            itemCount: _listViewData.length,
            gridDelegate:
                SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2),
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Card(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    AspectRatio(
                      aspectRatio: 18.0 / 13.0,
                      child: Image.network(
                        _listViewDataImage[index],
                        fit: BoxFit.fill,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16.0, 12.0, 16.0, 8.0),
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            _listViewData[index],
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              );
            }),
      ),
    );
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The problem comes from `SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount`:

> Creates grid layouts with a fixed number of tiles in the cross axis 
> This delegate creates grids with **equally sized** and spaced tiles.

I recommend you to use [flutter_staggered_grid_view:](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view#-installing-tab-) and to give up to AspectRatio widget. More about tiles [here](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view#tiles).

```
body: StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
   crossAxisCount: 2,
   itemCount: 6,
   itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => 
     Card(
       margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
       child: Container(
         child: Column(
           crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
           children: [
            Image.network('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/66/An_up-close_picture_of_a_curious_male_domestic_shorthair_tabby_cat.jpg',
              fit: BoxFit.fill,
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16.0, 12.0, 16.0, 8.0),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Text("Cat",textAlign: TextAlign.center),
                ],
            ),
         )],
       ),
     )
   ),
   staggeredTileBuilder: (int index) =>
     StaggeredTile.fit(1),
)
```

Comment: it nicely solve my problem the first about card, and the second about overflow bottom because of the fixed size, thank a lot ...

Answer (score 16):

You want to wrap your card in a `Column` because the inner Column take full height

```
 Column(children: <Widget>[
      Card(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            AspectRatio(
              aspectRatio: 18.0 / 13.0,
              child: Image.network(
               "https://picsum.photos/200",
                fit: BoxFit.fill,
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16.0, 12.0, 16.0, 8.0),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    "Just add your desired image size (width & height) after our URL, and you'll get a random image.",
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      )
])
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Try **[flutter_staggered_grid_view](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view#-installing-tab-)** package.

In the pubspec.yaml , add the following dependency:

```
dependencies:
  flutter_staggered_grid_view: any
```

In your library , add the following import:

```
import 'package:flutter_staggered_grid_view/flutter_staggered_grid_view.dart';
```

**Example:**

```
  StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
  crossAxisCount: 4,
  itemCount: 8,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => new Container(
      color: Colors.green,
      child: new Center(
        child: new CircleAvatar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          child: new Text('$index'),
        ),
      )),
  staggeredTileBuilder: (int index) =>
      new StaggeredTile.count(2, index.isEven ? 2 : 1),
  mainAxisSpacing: 4.0,
  crossAxisSpacing: 4.0,
),
```

> Use it like [GridView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GridView-class.html)

**Output:**

[image]

---

**Constructors** :

The **[StaggeredGridView](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_staggered_grid_view/latest/flutter_staggered_grid_view/StaggeredGridView-class.html)** follow the same constructors convention than the **[GridView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GridView-class.html)**.
There are two more constructors: `countBuilder` and `extentBuilder`. These constructors allow you to define a builder for the layout and a builder for the children.

**Tiles** :

A **[StaggeredGridView](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_staggered_grid_view/latest/flutter_staggered_grid_view/StaggeredGridView-class.html)** needs to know how to display each tile, and what widget is associated with a tile.

A **[tile](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_staggered_grid_view/latest/flutter_staggered_grid_view/StaggeredTile-class.html)** needs to have a fixed number of cell to occupy in the cross axis. For the extent in the main axis you have **03 options**:

1. You want a fixed number of cells => use `StaggeredTile.count`.
2. You want a fixed extent => use `StaggeredTile.extent`.
3. You want a variable extent, defined by the content of the tile
   itself => use `StaggeredTile.fit`.